# Problems using React JS and WebSockets

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, recharts

I am learning about these technologies (React JS, Node, WebSockets) and working on a project that uses websockets to display information on graphs in real time.

I have a state in my component that stores an array of objects with different attributes.

When I make a POST request to my server the record is saved in the database (Made in PostgreSQL) and I notify the client to do the update

My problem is that when I refresh the page it stops working and I need to restart the server to be able to see the changes in the graph again.

**SERVER**

```
io.on('connection', client => {

  app.post("/registros/nuevo", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let insertar = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO registro 
      (fecha, hora, temperatura, presion, humedad, viento, viento_max, radiacion, precipitacion)
      VALUES 
      ('${req.body.fecha}', '${req.body.hora}', ${req.body.temperatura}, ${req.body.presion},
        ${req.body.humedad}, ${req.body.viento}, ${req.body.viento_max}, ${req.body.radiacion}, 
        ${req.body.precipitacion});`).then(() => { client.emit('new: data', 'updated') });
      res.json({ message: "Recibido" });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  });
});
```

**CLIENT**

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([])

 const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/registros");
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            setData(jsonData);
            setCurrent(jsonData[jsonData.length - 1])
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
       getData()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() =>{
            socket.on('new: data', (c) =>{
            console.log(c)
            getData()
        })
    }, []);
```

I know that my code isn't the best, and thank u for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, my mistake was put the request inside of socket body

```
app.post("/registros/nuevo", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let insertar = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO registro
    (fecha, hora, temperatura, presion, humedad, viento, viento_max, radiacion, precipitacion)
    VALUES 
    ('${req.body.fecha}', '${req.body.hora}', ${req.body.temperatura}, ${req.body.presion}, ${req.body.humedad}, ${req.body.viento}, ${req.body.viento_max}, ${req.body.radiacion}, ${req.body.precipitacion});`)
    io.emit('new: data', 'Actualizado')
    res.sendStatus(204)
  } catch (err) {
    res.sendStatus(500)
  }
});
```